# Curving text in flex without converting to raster graphics?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Can you add curve effects to text in flash without converting it to a raster format?  Either applying the effect straight to the text, or converting the text to a path and applying the curve effect to the resultant path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? http://blog.tsclausing.com/post/49